# Google AppEngine localhost Datastore resetting on server startup

Tags: google-app-engine, configuration, persistence, google-cloud-datastore, reset

Whenever I start a debugging session in IntelliJ IDEA, my AppEngine localhost Datastore is reset (i.e., I lose all data that was persisted during a previous debugging session).

Any idea on how to configure my AppEngine debug server in order to keep my data persisted?

Comment: It works for me. There used to be a problem with GWT + GAE: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-50376 What version of Idea are you using?

Comment: I am currently using IDEA 11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Execute dev_appserver.py or dev_appserve.sh over a command line, if you do not set the flag to reset the datastore, it should not be reseted.